# Fullcalendar auto update calendar on multiple computers

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar, real-time-updates, fullcalendar-5

My wife and I both use the one instance of `fullcalendar` on a website I have built and when she creates a new event on the calendar on her computer, I want it to show up on mine without refreshing. Google calendar does this if we are working on the same calendar and I am wondering if there is a way to get `fullcalendar` to do it so that we are not both entering an event into the same timeslot.

I know I can use `calendar.refetchEvents()` with a timer, but I'm after something that won't keep polling the server.

Comment: In that case you'd need server-sent events or websockets so you can have data pushed from the server, rather than pulled by the client. That's not specific to fullCalendar itself.

Comment: (Even then, it doesn't _guarantee_ that you won't enter data in the same slots, because data could cross in transit, but certainly it makes it a lot less likely, if you're getting near-real-time updates. Of course you can also have some server-side validation which prevents that more robustly as well, but knowing in advance that the slot is taken means you're less likely to waste time even attempting to create overlapping events).